# How to cocat a datetime type field and a float type field. After that parse as a datetime datatype field (daypilot calendar)

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, webforms, concatenation

My teacher told me to select columndate cocat columntime as column3, then parse column3 as datetime datatype. He says I can't change the database datatype and I need to use those 4 column field start_date, end_date, start_time and end_time as it's in a server so he told me to do this.

He meant to combine start_date field and start_time field as one column in the code, then convert it to datetime type also done in the code. Same goes for end date field and end_time field. That means for example, start_date and start_time for record 1 will become 3/4/2014 9:00:00AM, end_date and end_time for record 1 will become to 3/4/2014 12:00:00PM.

so below are my codes, it's for a scheduler/timetable, which is called daypilot. So can help me in the query for the converting? in the code below there is a start_date and end_date, that is to be replaced by the datetime datatype that is finally parsed. help man

**MY SCHEDULE TABLE**
[image]

**MY DAYPILOT CONTROL PROPERTIES**

[image]

**IDEAL OUTPUT IF CODE WORKS... THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE. I have test this using two datetime column in a table which works.**
[image]

```
public partial class number2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 03, 24));
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days);
            DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)
    {        
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, PURPOSE, [START_DATE], [END_DATE] FROM [Schedule]  WHERE NOT (([END_DATE] <= @start) OR ([START_DATE] >= @end))", constr);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
}
```

**following @Trafz codes and it worked. this is the answer.**

```
public partial class number2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(new DateTime(2014, 04, 03));
            //DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = dbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days);
            DataBind();
        }

    }

    private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, PURPOSE, [START_DATE], [END_DATE], [START_TIME], [END_TIME] FROM [Schedule]", constr);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["START_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["START_TIME"]);
            dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["END_DATE"], dt.Rows[i]["END_TIME"]);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(object date, object time)
    {
        if (date == null)
        {
            // Add some logic for this scenario. Here are 2 examples:
            //throw new ArgumentNullException("date");
            //date = DateTime.MaxValue;
        }
        if (time == null)
        {
            // Add some logic for this scenario.
            //throw new ArgumentNullException("time");
            //time = 0;
        }

        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        float hoursAndMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(time);

        return CombineDateAndTime(dt, hoursAndMinutes);
    }
    public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(DateTime date, float time)
    {
        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)time / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        float remainder = time - (hours * 100);
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)remainder, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        DateTime returnDate = date.Date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
        return returnDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do this: `da.Fill(dt);`, you can to alter the data it received.

Here's a code-snippet of how I think you COULD combine your 2 columns into 1 DateTime:

```
public static void JustSomeMethodToTestTheConvertion()
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
    float time = 900;
    DateTime concatDate = CombineDateAndTime(date, time);
    Console.WriteLine(concatDate);
}

public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(DateTime date, float time)
{
    int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)time / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    float remainder = time - (hours * 100);
    int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)remainder, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    return date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
}
```

So you would need to loop through your data and do something like this and then fill it in.

To reply to your comment:

```
private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, PURPOSE, [START_DATE], [END_DATE] FROM [Schedule]  WHERE NOT (([END_DATE] <= @start) OR ([START_DATE] >= @end))", constr);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows[i]["YourConcatDateColumn"] = CombineDateAndTime(dt.Rows[i]["Date"], dt.Rows[i]["Time"]);
    }

    return dt;
}

public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(object date, object time)
{
    if (date == null)
    {
        // Add some logic for this scenario. Here are 2 examples:
        //throw new ArgumentNullException("date");
        //date = DateTime.MaxValue;
    }
    if (time == null)
    {
        // Add some logic for this scenario.
        //throw new ArgumentNullException("time");
        //time = 0;
    }

    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    float hoursAndMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(time);

    return CombineDateAndTime(dt, hoursAndMinutes);
}
public static DateTime CombineDateAndTime(DateTime date, float time)
{
    int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)time / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    float remainder = time - (hours * 100);
    int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)remainder, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    DateTime returnDate = date.Date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
    return returnDate;
}
```

But you would need to `SELECT` all of the needed columns and also change the `"YourConcatDateColumn"` parts to the name of the proper columns to use. E.g. `["START_DATE"]` and `["START_TIME"]`.

Comment: I just suddenly found out that for DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.AddDays((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date);  It will use the previous week of current week. @Trafz

Comment: I found it. This is better. DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = DayPilot.Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek(DateTime.Today); @Trafz

Comment: Well, if you read the code you got from me, then you'll notice that it has a `-` in front of `(int)DateTime.Now‌`. That's why it "suddenly" doesn't work anymore. The reason I added that weird logic, was because I don't know exactly how they've made `Utils.Week.FirstWorkingDayOfWeek()`. Though I see that I forgot to add 1 day, so it probably wouldn't have worked properly anyway. As long as you got it to work, then it's great :)